# Requisição https (webservice) da Fazenda Pública de São Paulo

Tags: web-service, xml, r, httr

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição https do Webservice da Fazenda Pública de São Paulo, mas não sei onde estou errando.

Este é o endereço:

http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/contas/webservice.shtm

Segundo a orientação do [manual](http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/contas/WebserviceTransparenciaManual.pdf), não é necessário fazer autenticação.

Basicamente, eu quero a despesa empenhada de um determinado ano. Meu código é este aqui:

```
library(XML)
library(httr)
a<-GET('https://webservices.fazenda.sp.gov.br/WSTransparencia/TransparenciaServico.asmx?',
   query = list(op="ConsultarDespesas",
                ano="2015",
                flagCredor=0,
                flagEmpenhado=1,
                flagLiquidado=0,
                flagPago=0))
b<-xmlParse(a)
```

Obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
Erro: 1: Opening and ending tag mismatch: p line 52 and br
2: Opening and ending tag mismatch: span line 49 and br
3: EntityRef: expecting ';'
4: Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 43 and p
5: AttValue: " or ' expected
6: attributes construct error
7: Couldn't find end of Start Tag font line 85
8: Opening and ending tag mismatch: p line 85 and font
9: Opening and ending tag mismatch: span line 83 and p
10: AttValue: " or ' expected
11: attributes construct error
12: Couldn't find end of Start Tag font line 90
13: Opening and ending tag mismatch: pre line 87 and font
14: AttValue: " or ' expected
15: attributes construct error
16: Couldn't find end of Start Tag font line 97
17: Opening and ending tag mismatch: div line 41 and font
18: AttValue: " or ' expected
19: attributes construct error
20: Couldn't find end of Start Tag font line 98
21: Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 39 and font
22: AttValue: " or ' expected
23: attributes construct error
24: Couldn't find end of
```

Alguém pode me ajudar nisso?

Comment: Já tentei fazer extaamente essa requisição e não consegui. Aqui não da erro quando faço `b <-xml2::read_html(content(a, "text"))`. Mas não sei se isso atende.

Comment: Oi Daniel, resolvi o problema. Vou colocar a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabei resolvendo parcialmente (funciona somente a partir de 2010) a questão com a função `curlPerfom()` do pacote `RCurl`.
Eu peguei o exemplo [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717706/soap-request-in-r). A partir disso, eu obtive as informações sobre o *header* e o *body* [aqui](https://webservices.fazenda.sp.gov.br/WSTransparencia/TransparenciaServico.asmx?op=ConsultarDespesas) e criei uma função para extrair as despesas de um órgão governamental, cujo código eu obtenho [daqui](http://www.planejamento.sp.gov.br/noti_anexo/files/orcamento/orcamento2015.pdf), pois era somente disso que eu precisava.

Naturalmente, a pessoa pode incluir outras variáveis na função e ajustar o `paste0()`. Não sei se é a melhor solução, mas estou satisfeito porque terei condições manipular todas as despesas de São Paulo.

```
fazendaSP<-function(ano,codigo)
{

library(RCurl) 
library(XML)


  # O objeto (hd) abaixo contém contém o header 

hd<-c(Accept = "text/xml",
        Accept = "multipart/*",
        'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        SOAPAction= "http://fazenda.sp.gov.br/wstransparencia/ConsultarDespesas"
        )

# O objeto (body) abaixo contém o body com as respectivas variáveis. Meu interesse está somente no código do órgão e no ano.
body<-paste0(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
  <AutenticacaoHeader xmlns="http://fazenda.sp.gov.br/wstransparencia">
  <Usuario></Usuario>
  <Senha></Senha>
  </AutenticacaoHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
  <ConsultarDespesas xmlns="http://fazenda.sp.gov.br/wstransparencia">
  <ano>'
    ,ano,
    '</ano>
    <codigoOrgao>',
    codigo,
    '</codigoOrgao> # Quero somente a despesa do MP
      <codigoUo></codigoUo>
      <codigoUnidadeGestora></codigoUnidadeGestora>
      <codigoFonteRecursos></codigoFonteRecursos>
      <codigoTipoLicitacao></codigoTipoLicitacao>
      <codigoFuncao></codigoFuncao>
      <codigoSubfuncao></codigoSubfuncao>
      <codigoPrograma></codigoPrograma>
      <codigoAcao></codigoAcao>
      <codigoFuncionalProgramatica></codigoFuncionalProgramatica>
      <codigoMunicipio></codigoMunicipio>
      <codigoCategoria></codigoCategoria>
      <codigoGrupo></codigoGrupo>
      <codigoModalidade></codigoModalidade>
      <codigoElemento></codigoElemento>
      <naturezaDespesa></naturezaDespesa>
      <flagCredor>0</flagCredor>
      <cgcCpfCredor></cgcCpfCredor>
      <nomeCredor></nomeCredor>
      <flagEmpenhado>1</flagEmpenhado>
      <flagLiquidado>0</flagLiquidado>
      <flagPago>0</flagPago>
      </ConsultarDespesas>
      </soap:Body>
      </soap:Envelope>'
    )

h = basicTextGatherer() # A função curlPerfom não deposita os resultados em lugar algum,
# Eu preciso desse objeto (h) com funções que coletam o conteúdo.

### Agora estamos prontos, temos o header, o body, a função para coletar e, além disso, devido a um provavel
### malfuncionamento do ssl, pedir para ignorar a verificação 
curlPerform(url = "https://webservices.fazenda.sp.gov.br/WSTransparencia/TransparenciaServico.asmx?",
            httpheader = hd,
            postfields = body,
            .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE),
            writefunction=h$update
)
a<-h$value()
b<-xmlParse(a)
c<-xmlToList(b)
d<-do.call("rbind",c$Body$ConsultarDespesasResponse$ConsultarDespesasResult$ListaItensDespesa)
e<-as.data.frame(d)
rownames(e)<-1:nrow(e)
return(e)
}
```